# Div can't be resized beyond content

Tags: css, html, microsoft-edge

[image]

The Div didn't stretch to the end of the screen

CSS:

```
#page {
  background-color:white;
  color:black;
  position:absolute;
  top:0vh;
  left:2vw;
  width:96vw:
  height:100vh;
}
```

The height is supposed to be 100 viewport-heights.
The width is supposed to be 96 viewport-widths.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SpaceOS</title>
        <style>
        #page {
          background-color:white;
          color:black;
          position:absolute;
          top:0vh;
          left:2vw;
          width:96vw:
          height:100vh;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <h1 class="title">SpaceOS</h1>
            <p class="error">Raspberry pi compatibility coming soon.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now for the cliché, pls help.

Comment: The problem is simply a typo. You have `width:96vw:` instead of `width:96vw;`.

Comment: Try `width: 96vw;` (with a semi-colon). You have a colon in there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple syntax error from what I can see. When you declare the width of #page, you didn't put a semicolon, you put a colon instead. So just change this:

```
  left:2vw;
  width:96vw:
  height:100vh;
```

to this:

```
  left:2vw;
  width:96vw;
  height:100vh;
```

and problem solved!

Comment: Rip, I'm an idiot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding before styling #page:

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: That just added scrollbars. Thanks tho.